# how to pass data using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using `ASP.NET Webforms` and I have the following function which returns multiple `lat` and `lon` values:

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        if (response.routes && response.routes.length > 0) {
            var routes = response.routes;
            for (var j = 0; j < routes.length; j++) {
                var points = routes[j].overview_path;
                var ul = document.getElementById("vertex");
                for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    li.innerHTML = getLiText(points[i]);
                    ul.appendChild(li);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

function getLiText(point) {

    var lat = point.lat(),
        lng = point.lng();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx/gpsdata",
        data: { 'lat': point.lat() },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // response(data.d);
            alert(point);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return "lat: " + lat + " lng: " + lng;
}

<div id="vertex-container">
    <label>Points</label>
    <ul id="vertex">
    </ul>
</div>
```

So not it will give me output as below:

[image]

Now I want to send these all data to c# method. For that I have add below method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string gpsdata(string lat)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyConn"].ToString();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into latdata values(username)", conn))
    {
       //my code
    }
}
```

But it is not working..

From the `javascript ajax` method it will not pass the any values to the c# web method and I am not able to insert that all values to my database.

So how can I do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 data: JSON.stringify({ 'lat': point.lat() })
```

Use `JSON.Stringfy` function while passing your json data.

Comment: Have u placed a break-point in code behind file? It should hit the server method.

Answer (score 0):

I notice an error in your webmethod

```
public static string gpsdata(string lat)
```

should be

```
public static string gpsdata(string lat, string lng)

//jQuery
var geoLoc = { 
    lat: point.lat(),
    lng: point.lat()
}
var parameter = JSON.stringify(geoLoc); 

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/gpsdata",
    data: parameter,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function () { },
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
        debugger;
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Comment: Well I should have been specific lol try this  url: "Default.aspx/gpsdata",

Comment: @Tolga What is the proper way of formatting? I am using 4 spaces.

Comment: 4 spaces is fine. Go with it ;)